# Form not loading controls for some users

Tags: performance, ms-access-2013

I created a split database w/ a networked distributable front-end application that users can download to their PC's for improved performance.  I tested this set-up myself and w/ another user and everything works as expected: forms open fine w/ or w/out data in corresponding tables.  However, I have some other users who can download the file and log in w/out issue, but **when they go to open the data entry form the form controls don't display** (e.g., no text/option boxes).  I'm inclined to think there is a system compatibility issue of some sort that is causing this to only occur for some users, but I have no idea where to start.  Any thoughts?

Using Access 2013

Comment: Possible reason: they have no write permissions on the backend folder or file. So Access sees the tables read-only and can't show the blank new record. Open a linked table directly in their frontend to see what's going on.

Comment: I initially thought that too, but my user table is located in the back-end so they would not have been able to log on if it were related to permissions.